# Is some compiler funny-business going on?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I am just testing out two simple expressions, although the opposite value yields the same result.

```
int main() {
    unsigned int a = 50, b = 33, c = 24, d = 12;

    if (a != b < c){
        /*a is not equal to b, so the bool is converted to 1 and 1 is less than c*/
        cout << "This is apparent" << endl;
    }

    if (a != b > c){
        /* a is not equal to b, so the bool is converted to one and 1 is not more than c.
         * The expression still evaluates to true.
         * Why is this? Is the compiler messing with something? */

        cout << "This is apparent" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this belongs on Stack Overflow. I've voted to close it on that basis; with a few more such votes, it should be migrated automatically.

Comment: In general, your first instinct should not be to suspect the compiler?

Comment: Your output is the same, no matter which code path you take.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman: I think you've missed the point.  The op wants to know why neither conditional is evaluating to true.

Comment: @Brian Then why do both ``if`` statements have the same code (``cout << "This is apparent" << endl;``)? BTW, I am in agreement with Keith Thompson's answer.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman: Sorry, I misspoke.  Rather, both conditionals are true.  So, having them both output the same thing doesn't matter; the OP can tell he has a problem since the output appears twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only "funny business" is that the compiler is doing exactly what it's supposed to do.

`<`, `>`, and the other relational operators bind more tightly than `=` and `!=`, so this:

```
if (a != b < c)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if (a != (b < c))
```

Since `a` is neither `0` nor `1`, it will be unequal to the result of any equality or relational operator.

To compare the result of `!=` to `c`, you can write:

```
if ((a != b) < c)
```

You should use parentheses when you're unsure of the relative precedence of the operators you're using, or when your readers are likely to be unsure. I know C pretty well, but I had to check the standard to be sure of the relative precedence of the relational and equality operators.

But in this particular case, I can't think of any reason to do what you're doing in the first place (other than as an exercise to understand expression evaluation, which is perfectly reasonable if that's what you're doing). If I saw `if ((a != b) < c)` in real-world code, I'd probably ask the author to rewrite it.

Comment: ...And you should be using parentheses to make your intent clear anyway.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. It gets straight to the heart of the problem with a clear explanation, then goes on to make important side points.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Yes, it is an exercise.